# Powershell generate XML file

Tags: xml, powershell, datatable

I have a powershell script that spool the result of an Stored Procedure in SQL Server into a DataTable. This DT has only one row that is an XML string:

```
#-----------------------
#-- XML file Creation --
#-----------------------
[String]$Step = "XML file Creation."
&{
  foreach ($row in $dt_table1.Rows){ 
  $row[0].ToString().Trim()
  } }| set-content $DestinationXMLFilePath
```

However, the output file generated by this creates a TXT file not in an XML format, if the line is too long it automatically put a new line to continue and this is not correct.

Is there a way to generate an XML in XML format?

Comment: "if the line is too long it automatically put a new line to continue and this is not correct." - can you show us such a line and what happens to it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, adding the **-NonewLine** parameter to the code:

```
#-----------------------
#-- XML file Creation --
#-----------------------
[String]$Step = "XML file Creation."
&{
  foreach ($row in $dt_table1.Rows){ 
  $row[0].ToString().Trim()
  } }| set-content $DestinationXMLFilePath -NoNewLine
```

Comment: If your `$dt_table1` only ever has one row anyway, you don't need a `foreach` loop.